# Custom push notification server / service

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Since Parse has announced that their closing their cloud services, i've been playing with the idea of making my own push notification server, preferrably in .NET. I've been doing some research, but I have not found anything really useful as of yet, in regards to creating a custom notification server.

What i have found though, is [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/). GCM seems to fulfill my needs, as i have to support push to both iOS and Android. Also, it doesn't seem to have any major limitations and seems to be completely free.

The whole idea of this though, would be to not being dependent on another 3rd party service, like Parse or Google, as i need this for many project, and cannot be bothered to change service whenever the provider decides that they are shutting down.

I would prefer to create my own notification server, but to be honest, Google Cloud Messaging looks really good. Is it something that is possible to do, in a reasonable amount of time, in .NET / .NET Web API ?